# Error: Cannot find control with path - Angular formControlName doesn't see a key that {{form.value | json}} shows

Tags: angular, firebase, nosql, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

When creating a new Worker with formBuilder, I need to pass the references (Firestore keys) to the services that the Worker offer because I want them (keys) to be formControlName directives on checkboxes:

```
 buildForm = () => {this.workerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
    services: this.formBuilder.group({
    })})
```

Inside the field "services" I want to have pairs - firebaseServiceKey: false. I am not sure if I can do this (add a property to an object) dynamically with *ngFor so I made a function:

```
mapControlPaths = () => {
    this.servicesService.getServicesKeys().subscribe(res => res.map(key => 
      this.workerForm.value.services[key] = false
        ))}
```

It seems to work fine (I see the result with pre tags):

```
"services": {
    "0IyxGP51E3rSvUZfJdPP": false,
    "80MBmjEOeSc44jluVWjf": false,
    "ELaMKPQZ0ejHeaOzzBtS": false
  }
```

However, when I add the following lines in HTML template:

```
  <div formGroupName="services">
        <label *ngFor="let service of services" for="services">{{service.name}}
            <input formControlName="{{service.key}}" type="checkbox" name="services" id="{{service.key}}">
        </label>
    </div>
```

I get the error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'services ->
>   0IyxGP51E3rSvUZfJdPP'.

But if I type the keys manually (without a function) and my component starts with this:

```
buildForm = () => {
this.workerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', { validators: [Validators.required] }],
  services: this.formBuilder.group({
    "0IyxGP51E3rSvUZfJdPP": false,
    "80MBmjEOeSc44jluVWjf": false,
    "ELaMKPQZ0ejHeaOzzBtS": false
  })
})
```

All works fine. I thought it's an async problem, but apparently it is not. So what's the problem?

Comment: You can’t use interpolation that way. You can use [formControlName] = “service.key”

Comment: @MikeOne Actually, I can. It works well both ways. But thanks for your time anyway. I am almost sure everything's well connected because if I type firestore keys by myself, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a FormArray instead of FormGroup because you have an array of key-value pairs. (Note that the variable names come from my Stackblitz example and could be somewhat different from your code but I hope you catch the idea.)

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
      services: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
```

After that you should push the key-value array to you control array:

```
    this.servicesArray.forEach(x => {
      control.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          key: x.key,
          value: x.value,
        })
      )
    });
```

Please, check this Stackblitz example I made with two components, the "GoodComponent" and then "BadComponent": https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rk9tw. The errors show in the console come from the bad component.